# Where can I find good web hosting reviews?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, server, website-review

I'm trying to choose a new hosting service for a WordPress blog, I've stumbled upon several services and most of them look good, so I was trying to find reviews from current user to see what they have to say, is there any website where I can find people's thoughts on the different web hosting companies / services?.

Comment: If this were asked today it would be closed as off topic.  Questions that ask for recommendations are not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

Web Hosting Talk is a good forum and you should be able to find user reviews for most hosts. My current host's participation in their review thread convinced me to sign up. They have ended up being the best host I've dealt with over the past 8 years.

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/

Comment: It seems like this is a good site as other people have also recommended it to me, I'm going to check it right now :), thanks...

Answer (score 0):

A few Google searches can also be helpful. I ended up using AN Hosting for shared hosting, but Googled things like `"an hosting" sucks` before signing up with them.

Try to find a host that hasn't created major problems for all their customers or suffered significant downtime, etc. But keep in mind that any large business will have some negative reviews. No host is perfect and you'll probably have to overlook a few negative comments.

Comment: Yeah that's right, I think I'll need to make a careful selection before choosing the fittest hosting provider for my site...